# Problemas para insertar un valor automáticamente en referencia otra tabla

Tags: python, web2py

Buen día,
Estoy usando el framework web2py, Tengo estas tablas:

```
db.define_table('productos',
        Field('producto', 'string', label=T('Producto / Servicio')),
        Field('precio', 'decimal(11, 2)', default=Decimal('0.00'), requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='Ingrese un precio'), IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(0, None, error_message='Importe inválido')]),
    format='%(producto)s')

db.define_table('boletas_registros',
        Field('fecha_registro', 'datetime', label='Fecha registro', default=now, writable=False),
        Field('cliente', 'reference clientes', label=T('Cliente')),
        Field('ticket_group', 'reference tickets_groups'),
        Field('numero_ticket', 'string'),
        Field('padron', 'string', label=T('Pad')),
        Field('placa', 'string', label=T('Placa')),
        Field('producto', 'reference productos'),
        Field('precio', 'decimal(11, 2)', label=T('Precio')),
        Field('total', 'decimal(11, 2)', label=T('Total')),
    format='%(ticket_group)s - %(numero_ticket)s')
```

La tabla "boletas_registro" esta relacionado con la tabla productos, Lo que deseo hacer es que al ingresar un registro seleccionando un producto automaticamente aparezca el precio dado en la tabla productos.
Por ejemplo el registro en la tabla productos es: producto: leche, precio:2.70
cuando seleccione en la tabla boletas_registro dicho producto y lo guarde me debe jalar el precio establecido en la tabla producto, para ello estoy usando la siguiente funcion:

```
def data_insert_boletas_registros(values, id, table):
    try:
        producto= values['producto']
        data = db.productos(db.productos.producto == producto)
        ##producto = data['id']
        precio = data['precio']
        db[table][id] = dict(##producto=producto,
                             precio=precio)
        print producto

    except:
        pass
    return
```

y finalmente asi:

```
db.boletas_registros._after_insert.append(lambda values, id: data_insert_boletas_registros(values, id, 'boletas_registros'))
```

pero no me esta jalando ningún valor a la hora de hacer los registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]